# Why Left Join is so slow?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I have query like next:

```
SELECT MV1.Column2,
    MV1.Column3,
    T2.Column3,
    T3.Column5
FROM MaterializedView1 MV1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.Id = MV1.T2_Id
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.Id = T2.T3_Id
```

MV1 have more then 5M rows, and I refresh this materialized view every day. T2 have about 500K rows and T3 have about 1M rows.
T2 and T3 have primary keys "Id" and **valid** indexes for these columns. Ok, I build Explain plan, which display me, that for this joins Oracle will use **index *full* scan** with **nested loops** and query cost is too large (more then 1M).
If I use simple:

```
SELECT T2.Column3
FROM Table2 T2
WHERE
T2.Id = 1

SELECT T3.Column5
FROM Table3 T3
WHERE
T3.Id = 10
```

then Oracle use INDEX UNIQUE SCAN and cost of this querys is 1.
Cost of select from MaterializedView1 is about 1000.
Can anybody tell me, whats wrong and how I can optimize my query?

Comment: Show us the execution plan and the exact index definitions for those tables.

Comment: You probably do not have indexes on MV1 for T2_Id and on T2 for T3_Id.  So it will have to go with full scans to do the join.

Comment: Is there an index on MaterializedView1.T2_Id and Table2.T3_Id?

Comment: As explained in the first comment, without the execution plan and the index definitions, all the answer you could get will be _pure speculations_.

Comment: Yes,  Sylvain Leroux, I agree with you, I hate question like my too, but I forgot to copy-paste Execution plan from office computer

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try this and check.

```
SELECT MV1.Column2,
    MV1.Column3,
    T2.Column3,
    T3.Column5
FROM (Select column2,column3 from MaterializedView1 group by column2,column3) MV1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.Id = MV1.T2_Id
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.Id = T2.T3_Id
```

Answer (score -1):

My first guess is get rid of the materialized view and create a "real" table instead. You can delete (or truncate) / update that table with the frequency you have today for the materialized view but I have the feeling your query is going to be faster.

As far as I recall (until version 11) materialized views are good as "snapshot" for report purposes but they lose their grip if you use them in "complex" queries.

Comment: A materialized view **is** (phyiscally) identical  to a table. There is no difference in performance between a table and a MVIEW. The claim that they are slow in complex queries is plain wrong.

Comment: To completely honest, that is nonsense. A materialized view is nothing but a table with some additional metadata.

Comment: It might be, it depends on how Oracle treats indexes and execution plan. I wouldn't be surprised to find out there's a slightly difference that may lead to lose performances. My answer comes from a previous similar experience but with a quite old Oracle version.